# Tab and delete using javascript is not working in mozilla

Tags: javascript, asp.net

In the below code i have 2 js function for accepting alphabets and alphanumeric in which when i tested in mozilla firefox the tab is not workingfor alphanumeric and tab ,backspace ,delete is not working for alphabets pls anyone help me to solve the issue.

```
function alphanumeric(e) {

var k;
document.all ? k = e.keyCode : k = e.which;
return ((k > 64 && k < 91) || (k > 96 && k < 123) || k == 8 ||k == 9|| k == 32 || (k >= 48 && k <= 57));
```

}

```
function onlyAlphabets(e, t) {
    try {

        if (window.event) {
            var charCode = window.event.keyCode;
        }
        else if (e) {
            var charCode = e.which;
        }
        else { return true; }
        if ((charCode > 64 && charCode < 91) || (charCode == 9 && charCode == 8)|| (charCode > 96 && charCode < 123))
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
    catch (err) {
        alert(err.Description);
    }
}
```

Comment: What event are you binding to? Can you make a fiddle that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: I am binding onkeypress event  onkeypress="return alpha(event);"

 onkeypress="return onlyAlphabets(event,this);"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works in both FF and Chrome:

```
function alphanumeric(e) {

    var k;
    k = e.keyCode || e.charCode;
    return ((k > 64 && k < 91) || (k > 96 && k < 123) || k == 8 || k == 9 || k == 32 || (k >= 48 && k <= 57));
}

function onlyAlphabets(e, t) {
    try {

        if (window.event) {
            var charCode = window.event.keyCode;
        } else if (e) {
            var charCode = e.keyCode || e.charCode;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
        if ((charCode > 64 && charCode < 91) || (charCode == 9 || charCode == 8) || (charCode > 96 && charCode < 123)) return true;
        else return false;
    } catch (err) {
        alert(err.Description);
    }
}
```

In `onlyAlphabetic()`

```
(charCode == 9 && charCode == 8)
```

should be:

```
(charCode == 9 || charCode == 8)
```

It's not possible for `charCode` to be equal to both of them at the same time.

In the `keypress` event, some keys have `keyCode == 0` so it's necessary to use `charCode`.

I suggest you read up on the difference between `keypress` and `keydown/keyup`, and `charCode` versus `keyCode`.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/4G4Q2/4/)

Comment: I tested it in Mozilla Firefox. TAB and Backspace both work correctly.

Comment: i am using html controls in asp.net

Comment: I don't know anything about asp.net, so I don't know how that would affect this.